# Unable to link photos or images to CodePen

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropbox, codepen

I am trying to link images and sound files to my [Code pen link](http://codepen.io/templenaylor/pen/KaQrwY?editors=1010) using a drop box share link.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row second-line">                  
        <div class="col-12">
            <div data-key="32" class="key">
                <kbd>BAR</kbd>
                <span class="sound">808</span>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>


<audio data-key="32" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqusqet38wnfexr/8081.wav?dl=0"></audio>
```

Neither the background image in my css file or sound file for my keyboard event is working. This works perfectly on my local files with local sounds/img.

I am trying however to use dropbox to upload them since you cannot upload files directly to CodePen.

Is this not supported? I could of sworn I have seen this done before, or maybe I am doing something wrong and Ignorant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdyEVW). I'm using the following code:

```html
<audio data-key="32">
  <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/bHRDoVQqFTHeLSx1YSynP8x5KaNfBIWyWzPG4zOvb9gBEyGBwNKImdcgmVZutije/file?dl=0&duc_id=dropbox_duc_id" type="audio/mpeg">Audio element not supported.
</audio>
```

Comment: This creates a unwanted soundbar, and the keyboard event does not work. I am trying to just play a sound from a keyboard event during every press of the spacebar.

Comment: I've updated my code to hide the player and trigger the sound with the spacebar.

Comment: This works thank you! Had to get this published by tonight. Just so I know for future reference, was my problem that I just didn't include the type="audio/mpeg" ?

Comment: You were defining the `source` inside the `audio` tag. The `source` tag needs to be a child to the `audio` element. This allows one `audio` declaration to have multiple formats (mp3, wav, mpeg, etc.) so the browser can choose the best file to play.

Comment: I see, I also noticed that your audio dropbox link is different then mine, also causing the issue. How did you go about just getting a link to the file itself?

Comment: You are correct, I forgot about that. I found the link by visiting the Dropbox link in your code, then viewing the source for that page, and grabbing the `source` from the `audio` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exact url of image so that it works fine.

```
https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AACwpnCZJSbovN9dSgYlI99tOkrG8qmOjDZQDmRE03cK9g/12/644080844/jpeg/32x32/3/1485946800/0/2/concert.jpg/EO2mxJ0FGA4gBygH/Q3aEGidy4B1EqGjlfgLcFxUvOVFcbpl2vDpixRv4ch8%2CznWx3nvuARPFZAfPD5avW9mleflEhRqDt5xXxIga2K8?dl=0&size=1280x960&size_mode=3
```

above url is the exact image url you can replace in your css.

```
background:  url('https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AACwpnCZJSbovN9dSgYlI99tOkrG8qmOjDZQDmRE03cK9g/12/644080844/jpeg/32x32/3/1485946800/0/2/concert.jpg/EO2mxJ0FGA4gBygH/Q3aEGidy4B1EqGjlfgLcFxUvOVFcbpl2vDpixRv4ch8%2CznWx3nvuARPFZAfPD5avW9mleflEhRqDt5xXxIga2K8?dl=0&size=1280x960&size_mode=3') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I got the background working, but what about the sound file? This is most important.

Comment: you can use src of dropbox audio `<audio controls>
  <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/OpMLl2K24D3p2pbz3fTVEfxcEanDm1imIiFLlBmzglfydrS1Sw6mhHCuYMbYaGmp/file?dl=0&duc_id=dropbox_duc_id" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>` works file!! check out.

Comment: This does not work, if you could link a codePen proving it does that would be great. Also, I am not looking for a sound control bar. Need the sound to play on keyboard event just once.

Comment: Awesome, yes. But anyway to remove that white soundbar? Can't have that. If this gets fixed you are definitely the answer!

Comment: which browser your using ?

Comment: I am using chrome. What about you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134549/discussion-between-ranjith-and-youngcoder).